# limiting postgreSQL update command

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with given structure, now I want to write a query that will transfer 2 xx product from status 1 to say status 2. the child code is irrelevant presently to me.

```
master_code| child_code | status_code
-----------|------------|------------
    xx     |    xx1     |     1
    xx     |    xx2     |     1
    xx     |    xx3     |     1
    xx     |    xx4     |     2
    xx     |    xx5     |     2
    yy     |    yy1     |     3
    yy     |    yy2     |     2
    zz     |    zz1     |     1
    zz     |    zz2     |     1
```

I have implemented basic checks, and when I used

```
update only product_child
set product_status=1
where product_status=2
```

all three xx's got code 2, I want control over that, I was expecting only one xx will get code change with this command

Comment: @wildplasser i wanted any one xx to change status child code are not in my consideration right now

Comment: *any one*: just randomly chosen, but only *exactly* one?

Answer (score 40):

If you do not care which row gets updated, something I would be very wary of doing (please add a PK to the table for this really), then you could use something like the following:

```
UPDATE
    product_child
SET
    product_status = 1
WHERE
    CTID IN ( SELECT CTID FROM product_child WHERE product_status = 2 and master_code = 'xx' LIMIT 1 )
```

CTID is a unique row identifier - and by limiting the subselect to 1 record we get back one CTID corresponding to a row that meets the WHERE clause.

Comment: well in current implementation any random child of a specific master will do.
master_code is a FK
for dealing with specific child i have a separate logic

Comment: Yeah I do believe you should have some logic picking out a specific one - even something as simple as oldest record would give you something to work with. This will pull back one random child as you requested.

Answer (score 7):

i found a way

```
update only product_child
set product_status =1
where product_child_code in (select product_child_code
                from product_child
                where product_code = get_product_code('Baby Crib') 
                and product_status = 2 
                limit 5)
```

Comment: The `only` keyword is only required if you are dealing with inherited tables. It does nothing on a "regular" table.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you should do this with a procedure :

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION  update_status() returns character varying as $$
declare
match_ret record;
begin
SELECT * INTO match_ret FROM product_child WHERE product_status = 2 LIMIT 1 for update ;
UPDATE product_child SET status_code = '1' where child_code = match_ret.child_code ;

return match_ret.child_code ;
commit;
end ;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

then call it with :

```
select * from update_status()
```

EDIT :
you can also do this with a 'with' :

```
WITH subRequest as (
SELECT child_code FROM product_child WHERE status = 2 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE
)
UPDATE product_child as p
FROM subRequest
WHERE p.child_code = subRequest.child_code ;
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The answer by John D. is right. I only would like to add that postgresql may use oids, and this is a good way to ensure an unique identifier, so I prefer this solution:

UPDATE
product_child
SET
product_status = 1
WHERE
oid = ( SELECT oid FROM product_child WHERE product_status = 2 and master_code = 'xx' LIMIT 1 );

Note that if your database has no oids, you can set by using:

ALTER TABLE product_child SET WITH OIDS;

Comment: `oids` have been deprecated for ages and should not be used. They have been completely removed with Postgres 12. Your `ALTER TABLE` does not work any longer.

Comment: Thank you horse...That's true, sorry because I didn't know about this deprecation. But anyway it is a deprecation for the future. Think about the most widely installed system centOS, whose version 8 will be maintained until 2029, and provides versions 9.6 and 10 of postgres (with oids)

Comment: Postgres 9.6 will be end-of-life in November 2021, Postgres 10 in November 2020. I don't see how CentOS can extend that for 9 years

Comment: I can't answer that. Anyway your solution may be good here, but globally don't ensure a unique deletion with multiple identical rows. oids did it, but of course if it is obsolete, is not the solution. I´ve solve this kind of problems with cursors, but it was with version 8,4 (surely) and I don't know if cursors are in use now and they are not easy to use.